Source separation of ECG and EMG signal using SSQ ssqueezepy
Currently I am working on implementing ECG and EMG source separation algorithm to better evaluate the activity of a muscle. I have try different approaches and the one below is the closet I have gotten to a successful one in which I peel-off the "ECG" components.
Now I want to use ssqueezepy and implement a better algorithm through stft or cwt. Any good Ideas on how to work this out? the goal is to source separate both signals and use this as the dataset for a kolmogorov arnold autoencoder network
I saw the post "How to remove ECG artifacts from EMG data?" where PCA was implemented and will test this soon
"""
Another method to extract the linear envelop
Overall method:

"""

# %%
# load the libraries required to run this script
# filesystem paths
from pathlib import Path

# Plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data loading and manipulation
from neo.io import CedIO
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import filtfilt, butter, iirnotch, sosfilt, find_peaks

from ssqueezepy.experimental import scale_to_freq
from ssqueezepy import Wavelet, cwt, imshow, icwt


# %%
# Envelop Functions
# moving RMS


def moving_window(tsx, window_size, step=1):
    """
    Returns a generator that yields a moving window of size `window_size` over `tsx` with a step size of `step`.

    Args:
        tsx (list): The input tsx.
        window_size (int): The size of the moving window.
        step (int, optional): The step size. Defaults to 1.

    Yields:
        list: A moving window of size `window_size` over `tsx`.
    """
    for i in range(0, len(tsx) - window_size + 1, step):
        yield tsx[i : i + window_size]


def rolling_mean(x: np.ndarray, N: int):
    """
    Calculate the moving window mean

    Args:
        x (np.ndarray): Input signal
        N (int): Window size

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: Moving window mean values
    """
    cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0))
    return (cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / float(N)


def rolling_rms(x: np.ndarray, N: int, skip: int = 1):
    """
    Calculate the moving window RMS of a signal.

    Parameters:
        x (numpy array): Input signal
        N (int): Window size
        skip (int, optional): Number of samples to skip between RMS calculations. Defaults to 1.

    Returns:
        numpy array: Moving window RMS values
    """
    xc = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0))
    rms_values = np.sqrt((xc[N:] - xc[:-N]) / N)
    # Handle edge cases by padding with NaNs
    rms_values = np.pad(
        rms_values, (N // 2, N // 2), mode="constant", constant_values=np.nan
    )
    # Return RMS values with the desired skip
    return rms_values[::skip]


def butter_lowpass_filter(tsx, cutOff, fs_=3, order=4):
    """
    Apply a lowpass filter to the time series.

    Args:
        tsx (array-like): Input time series tsx.
        cutOff (float): Cutoff frequency (Hz).
        fs_ (int, optional): Sampling frequency (Hz). Defaults to 3.
        order (int, optional): Filter order. Defaults to 4.

    Returns:
        array-like: Filtered time series tsx.
    """
    nyq = 0.5 * fs_
    normal_cutoff = cutOff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype="low", analog=False)
    return filtfilt(b, a, tsx)


def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    sos = butter(order, [low, high], analog=False, btype="band", output="sos")
    return sos


def butter_bandpass_filter(tsx, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    sos = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = sosfilt(sos, tsx)
    return y


def notch_filter(tsx, f0=60, Q=30, fs_: float = 3):
    """
    Apply a notch filter to the time series.

    Args:
        tsx (array-like): Input time series tsx.
        freq (float): Frequency to remove (Hz).
        fs (int, optional): Sampling frequency (Hz). Defaults to 3.
        order (int, optional): Filter order. Defaults to 4.

    Returns:
        array-like: Filtered time series tsx.
    """
    b, a = iirnotch(f0, Q, fs_)
    return filtfilt(b, a, tsx)


def ffc_filter(
    tsx: np.ndarray, alpha: float = -1.0, cutoff: float = 60.0, fs_: float = 24000.0
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Implements the FFC filter as described in [1].

    Apply the FFC filter to the input signal.

    y(k) = x(k) + (alpha * x)(k-N)
    x = input signal
    N = delay expressed in number of samples fs/f(w) where w is the target frequency to remove
    alpha = regulates aspects of the filter behavior (-1)

    [1] D. Esposito, J. Centracchio, P. Bifulco, and E. Andreozzi, “A smart approach to EMG envelope extraction and powerful denoising for human–machine interfaces,” Sci. Rep., vol. 13, no. 1, p. 7768, 2023, doi: 10.1038/s41598-023-33319-4.

    Parameters:
    tsx (np.ndarray): Input signal.
    alpha (float, optional): Filter behavior regulator. Defaults to -1.0.
    cutoff (float, optional): Target frequency to remove. Defaults to 60.0.
    fs (float, optional): Sampling frequency. Defaults to 24000.0.

    Returns:
    np.ndarray: Filtered signal.

    """
    assert tsx.ndim == 1, "Array must be one-dimensional"

    fs_ffc = int(fs_ / cutoff)  # delay expressed in number of samples
    return tsx + alpha * np.roll(tsx, -fs_ffc)  # apply the FFC filter


# %%

# define home (Drive were data is located)
home = Path.home()
# define the path to the data file
data_path = r"Documents\data\Methods-Paper_EMG\noisy_recording.smrx"
# build the path to the data file
working_path = home.joinpath(data_path)
print(working_path)
# %%
# load the data using CedIO
reader = CedIO(filename=working_path)
data = reader.read()
data_block = data[0].segments[0]
# %%
ch01_emg = data_block.analogsignals[0]
fs = ch01_emg.sampling_rate
# %%
width = 10  # Width in inches
height = 4  # Height in inches

# Create a sample plot with the specified figure size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))
ax.plot(ch01_emg.times, ch01_emg.magnitude)
# %%
# filter
start = int(fs * 75)
end = int(fs * 80)
fs = float(ch01_emg.sampling_rate)

ch01_emg_bp = butter_bandpass_filter(
    ch01_emg.magnitude.squeeze(), 0.1, 1000, fs, order=5
)
ch01_emg_notch = notch_filter(tsx=ch01_emg_bp, fs_=fs)
# %%
# ======================extracting the ECG=================================

# grab a segment of the data to work with
start = int(fs * 75)
end = int(fs * 80)
x_emg = ch01_emg_notch[start:end]  # use the notch filter data
# %%# Extract the wavelet transform
N = len(x_emg)
t = np.linspace(0, N / fs, N)
wavelet = Wavelet()
Wx, scales = cwt(x_emg, wavelet)

freqs_cwt = scale_to_freq(scales, wavelet, len(x_emg), fs=fs)

ikw = dict(abs=1, xticks=t, xlabel="Time [sec]", ylabel="Frequency [Hz]")
imshow(Wx, **ikw, yticks=freqs_cwt)
plt.plot(x_emg)
# %%
## Other methods
# # Universal threshold threshold = np.sqrt(2 * np.log(magnitude.size))
# thresholded_Wx = np.where(magnitude > threshold, Wx - threshold, 0)  # soft threshold
##

# Filter the Wx values
magnitude = np.abs(Wx)

# Bayesian threshold
threshold = np.sqrt(2 * np.log(magnitude.shape[0])) * np.std(magnitude)
thresholded_Wx = np.where(magnitude > threshold, Wx, 0)  # hard threshold

# %%
# plot the Wx matrix
ikw = dict(abs=1, xticks=t, xlabel="Time [sec]", ylabel="Frequency [Hz]")
imshow(thresholded_Wx, **ikw, yticks=freqs_cwt)
# %%
# reconstruct the signal from the threshold Wx matrix
x_emg_thr = icwt(thresholded_Wx, wavelet)
plt.plot(x_emg_thr)  # plot the new signal
# %% # find ecg peaks
ecg_signal = butter_bandpass_filter(x_emg_thr, 0.1, 150, fs, order=5)
plt.plot(ecg_signal)
# normalize the ecg signal
signal_normalized = (ecg_signal - np.mean(ecg_signal)) / np.std(ecg_signal)
plt.plot(signal_normalized)
# %%
# Find the peaks of the ecg signal
signal_std = np.std(signal_normalized)
hrt_max_freq = int(fs * 0.15)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(
    signal_normalized, distance=hrt_max_freq, height=signal_std
)  # Adjust the distance value as neededv

plt.plot(signal_normalized)
plt.plot(peaks, signal_normalized[peaks], "x")
plt.show()


# %%
def get_edges(arr, window_size):
    return [[max(0, idx - window_size), idx + window_size] for idx in arr]


# %%
# find the edges of the ECG signal
window_size = int(0.015 * fs)
edges = get_edges(peaks, window_size)

edges_array = np.array(edges)
diff = edges_array[:, 1] - edges_array[:, 0]
print(diff)  # print the length of the edges
# %%
a_test = np.zeros(x_emg_thr.shape[0])
for start, end in edges_array:
    a_test[start : end + 1] = 1
# %%

from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d

gaussian_peaks = gaussian_filter1d(a_test, sigma=100)

# Plot the result
plt.plot(gaussian_peaks)
plt.show()
# %%
plt.plot(gaussian_peaks)
plt.plot(x_emg * (1 - gaussian_peaks))
plt.plot(x_emg_thr * (1 - gaussian_peaks))
# %%




